# Javascript fine grain performance tweaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, profiling, firebug

I have been writing my first jQuery plugin and struggling to find a means to time how long different pieces of code take to run.

I can use firebug and console.time/profile. However, it seems that because my code executes so fast I get no results with profile and with time it spits out 0ms. ([Firebug profiling issue: "no activity to profile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690697/firebug-profiling-issue-no-activity-to-profile/2690846#2690846))

Is there a way to get the time at a greater level of detail that milliseconds in javascript?

UPDATE: I've put code that I want to test in a loop that loops it a million times, but it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: Why do you want to optimize functions which take 0ms and you don't plan to put in a loop?

Comment: Mainly because I'm a perfectionist. But also because its fun and it will be useful to know what are the fastest ways to do certain things when you do have to do them in a loop or they are expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your tests a number of times and then calculate how many operations per second are executed.

The easiest way to create such a test case is to use [the jsPerf website](http://jsperf.com/). It will generate a test case like this: http://jsperf.com/prime-numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
var startTime = new Date();
// do something
var totalTime = new Date() - startTime;
alert(totalTime);
```

Comment: This will only do milliseconds. So in the case of the code I want to test it will take 0ms.

Comment: You can add a loop with 1000 calls to solve the problem, but in general you should optimize only code fragments, which are really  slow and not which executing time is less then 1ms. In the case you spend million times more your and our time for this question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit weird but: Buy a really old computer. A Pentium 2 would do nicely. It is not an expensive solution and you get to dedicate a whole machine to your perfectionism. It's lovely seeing the scripts run and build up the page elements slow enough to see it.